# Custom Type and Mobile Optimized layout for Email Clients

Tags: mobile, email, fluid-layout, type, media-queries

I'm in need of your help in regards of Email Clients. I'm looking at developing some marketing email templates that have custom fonts and can be mobile optimized. I've been searching around the web for answers, but some results are misleading. Here is a recap.

For Type, apparently you can use Google fonts (@import-font-faces) but only Apple, Google and some Android Devices can render them. Result: Use a Google fonts and Arial as a fall back font. Does this sound right?

For Mobile, things get more complicated. There are 3 ways to do it. You can use Scalable Design, Fluid Design and Responsive Design.

Most of the examples I've found online are built using Head section styles or links to external style. But this doesn't sound right.

Does anyone know any resources and/or can recommend a solution on how to develop these email templates that would work for the majorety of email clients?

Thanks you in advance for you help!

AC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it gets even weirder. You will want to use tables for formatting and put your styles just after `<body>` instead of in `<head>`. There are lots of gotchas, like no background images. Psst: it's pretty much all because of Outlook. Surprised?

Your best bet is to use a test service like https://litmus.com/ or even a physical device lab to test the emails. Just like you'd test cross-browser compatibility for browsers.

If you're looking for a head start, http://responsiveemailpatterns.com/ has a number of templates that are ready for skinning and content.